# Spring + ReactJS - получить данные с сервера

Tags: javascript, java, spring, reactjs, rest

На бэке есть Spring-@RestController, который по URL ".../rest/users" возвращает JSON со списком юзеров.

На фронте есть React-component "UserList.jsx", который в методе render() должен нарисовать таблицу с полученных с бэка юзеров.
В React-router'e уже настроен соответствующий Route, связывающий наш URL с нашим компонентом.

Есть ли какая-то best-practice по получению данных с сервера в React-компоненте?

```
let users = получение_данных_с_сервера;
render() {
   return (
   users.map() => {
    ...........}  
 );
```

}